# how to compare dates by group, using value from other row if same row is missing

Tags: r, date, dplyr, na

Within a dataframe, how to compare dates set in two different columns (date_1 and date_2) by group (id) and, create a new column the result of that comparison ?

More precisely, for each id, I would like to know if one date_2 is anterior to the date_1.

There is always at least one date_1 and one date_2 for each ID but some may have more dates as for id N03.

For example, for the id N03, no date_2 is anterior to date_1. Thus a no should be produced. For the id N07, date_2 (2008-06-13) is anterior to date_1 (2009-06-09), thus for this id N07 a yes should be produce.

An dplyr::if_else or ifelse function produce only NA and does not work!

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
        group_by (id) %>%
        mutate (date_2_before_date_1 = ifelse (date_2 < date_1, "yes", "no"))
```

Please find below a minimal working example based on my dataset

```
id <- c("N03", "N03", "N03", "N07", "N07", "N16", "N16", "N17", "N17")
date_1 <- c("2008-05-13", "2010-12-14", NA, NA, "2009-06-09", NA,           "2011-05-03", "2018-05-03", NA)
date_2 <- c(NA, NA, "2011-12-19", "2008-06-13", NA, "2010-10-18", NA, NA, "2018-07-08")
df1 <- data.frame (id, date_1, date_2)

> df1
   id     date_1     date_2
1 N03 2008-05-13       <NA>
2 N03 2010-12-14       <NA>
3 N03       <NA> 2011-12-19
4 N07       <NA> 2008-06-13
5 N07 2009-06-09       <NA>
6 N16       <NA> 2010-10-18
7 N16 2011-05-03       <NA>
8 N17 2018-05-03       <NA>
9 N17       <NA> 2018-07-08
```

The desired output would be :

```
id <- c("N03", "N03", "N03", "N07", "N07", "N16", "N16", "N17", "N17")
date_1 <- c("2008-05-13", "2010-12-14", NA, NA, "2009-06-09", NA,           "2011-05-03", "2018-05-03", NA)
date_2 <- c(NA, NA, "2011-12-19", "2008-06-13", NA, "2010-10-18", NA, NA, "2018-07-08")
date_2_before_date_1 <- c("no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no")   
df2 <- data.frame (id, date_1, date_2, date_2_before_date_1)

> df2
   id     date_1     date_2 date_2_before_date_1
1 N03 2008-05-13       <NA>                   no
2 N03 2010-12-14       <NA>                   no
3 N03       <NA> 2011-12-19                   no
4 N07       <NA> 2008-06-13                  yes
5 N07 2009-06-09       <NA>                  yes
6 N16       <NA> 2010-10-18                  yes
7 N16 2011-05-03       <NA>                  yes
8 N17 2018-05-03       <NA>                   no
9 N17       <NA> 2018-07-08                   no
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Charles

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your target variable? Will there always be 1 `date_2` per each group?

Comment: Why for id 'N03', `date_1` was `NA` and `date_2` was `2011-12-19`, yielding `no`, but for 'N07' `date_1` was `NA` and `date_2` was `2008-06-13`, and the result was `yes`? Both `date_2`'s were compared with `NA`'s but you want different results

Comment: Thanks for editing your post. But it’s still unclear what should happen if a group has multiple `date_2`s that give different results? e.g., what should happen if `date_1 = c(NA, "2021-01-15", NA)` and `date_2 = c("2022-01-15", NA, "2019-01-15")`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyr::fill()`, make temporary helper columns to bring in dates from above or below, then use these to make your comparison:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(
    date_1_fill = date_1,
    date_2_fill = date_2
  ) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(date_1_fill, date_2_fill, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    date_2_before_date_1 = ifelse(date_2_fill < date_1_fill, "yes", "no"),
    .keep = "unused"
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  id    date_1     date_2     date_2_before_date_1
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <chr>               
1 N03   2008-05-13 NA         no                  
2 N03   2010-12-14 NA         no                  
3 N03   NA         2011-12-19 no                  
4 N07   NA         2008-06-13 yes                 
5 N07   2009-06-09 NA         yes                 
6 N16   NA         2010-10-18 yes                 
7 N16   2011-05-03 NA         yes                 
8 N17   2018-05-03 NA         no                  
9 N17   NA         2018-07-08 no
```

This assumes you want to maintain the structure of your dataset. If not, you may make life easier for yourself by consolidating your rows:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(date_2, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  drop_na(date_1) %>%
  mutate(
    date_2_before_date_1 = ifelse(date_2 < date_1, "yes", "no")
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  id    date_1     date_2     date_2_before_date_1
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <chr>               
1 N03   2008-05-13 2011-12-19 no                  
2 N03   2010-12-14 2011-12-19 no                  
3 N07   2009-06-09 2008-06-13 yes                 
4 N16   2011-05-03 2010-10-18 yes                 
5 N17   2018-05-03 2018-07-08 no
```